# "Zoom" in the most concentrated part of a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a scatter plot in matplot where I'm showing the spread of images width and height values. Is there a way to use the `plt.xlim` or another method to "zoom" in on the most concentrated values. Now I have a plot with many values ranging between 200 - 500, it would be nice to "zoom" in on them, and keep the xticks wider apart with the less populated values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a zoomed-in subplot.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 10))
ax_in = ax.inset_axes([0.6, 0.6, 0.35, 0.35])
x = np.random.chisquare(2, 1000)
y = np.random.chisquare(2, 1000)
ax.scatter(x, y)

ax_in.scatter(x, y)
ax_in.set_xlim(-0.5, 2)
ax_in.set_ylim(-0.5, 2)
```

result

[image]

Or,

use [set_xlim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html)

set scale to [log scale](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html)

use [alpha](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)